# Why is "_" getting removed from a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried entering the below code in the Chrome console:

```
var a = 16_11;
```

It's not inside `"` or `'`. And the output of `a` is 1611 instead of 16_11. Why is `_` getting removed?

[image: ConsoleOutput]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got a [**numeric separator**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) which is a proposal and actual shipping in V8 v7.5/Chrome 75.

> This feature enables developers to make their numeric literals more readable by creating a visual separation between groups of digits. Large numeric literals are difficult for the human eye to parse quickly, especially when there are long digit repetitions. This impairs both the ability to get the correct value / order of magnitude...
>
> ```
> 1000000000   // Is this a billion? a hundred millions? Ten millions?
> 101475938.38 // what scale is this? what power of 10?
> ```
>
> ...but also fails to convey some use-case information, such as fixed-point arithmetic using integers. For instance, financial computations often work in 4- to 6-digit fixed-point arithmetics, but even storing amounts as cents is not immediately obvious without separators in literals:
>
> ```
> const FEE = 12300;
> // is this 12,300? Or 123, because it's in cents?
>
> const AMOUNT = 1234500;
> // is this 1,234,500? Or cents, hence 12,345? Or financial, 4-fixed 123.45?
> ```
>
> Using underscores (_, U+005F) as separators helps improve readability for numeric literals, both integers and floating-point (and in JS, it's all floating-point anyway):
>
> ```
> 1_000_000_000           // Ah, so a billion
> 101_475_938.38          // And this is hundreds of millions
>
> let fee = 123_00;       // $123 (12300 cents, apparently)
> let fee = 12_300;       // $12,300 (woah, that fee!)
> let amount = 12345_00;  // 12,345 (1234500 cents, apparently)
> let amount = 123_4500;  // 123.45 (4-fixed financial)
> let amount = 1_234_500; // 1,234,500
> ```
>
> Also, this works on the fractional and exponent parts, too:
>
> ```
> 0.000_001 // 1 millionth
> 1e10_000  // 10^10000 -- granted, far less useful / in-range...
> ```

Some more sources:

- [ES proposal: numeric separators](https://2ality.com/2018/02/numeric-separators.html)
- [Numeric separators](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators)

```js
var a = 1_000;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Is having an id or class that begins with number following with underscore or hyphen: <div id="1_id_cms_page" class="active"> also not allowed as I got an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Numeric separators are not allowed at the end of numeric literals"

Comment: @heero, it has nothing to do with numbers. that is becuase of all `id` are mirrored as variable and they can not start with a number.

Answer (score 2):

Because Chrome [implements](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators) the experimental [numeric separator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator), which permits optional underscores between any digits in a number literal. Without that, it would be just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to do with that code snippet? 16_11 is not meaningful number, i think.

So if you want string 16_11, then

```
 var a = "16_11";
```

will work.

Comment: If you need more information before giving a proper answer, there is a comment section just for that. Also, his question doesn't have to be meaningful. He was trying to understand why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose it is introduced to increase the `readability` because some number can be large and difficult to read while programming. It just acts as `separator` here, so you can easily identify how many digits are there.

For example looking at below example you can easily say it is a `trillion` without putting much effort;

```js
var a = 1_000_000_000_000;

console.log(a);
```